# COMException visual studio designer

Tags: visual-studio-2013, winrt-xaml

I'm working on a project to make a custom control that works on both Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1. After I finished all the coding for my custom control which is inside a PCL project, I added a universal app project. After adding this I'm facing a strange error (at least to me), which I really need some help with. The error and its StackTrace is:-

```
COMException:Error HRESULT E-FAIL has been returned from a call to a com component.
at System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.IVector`1.InsertAt(UInt32 index, T value)
at System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.VectorToListAdapter.InsertAtHelper[T](IVector`1 _this, UInt32 index, T item)
at System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.VectorToListAdapter.Insert[T](Int32 index, T item)
```

The error appears everytime I start my solution and opening the MainPage.Xaml for either windows 8.1 or Windows Phone 8.1. Both xamls have only the code below inside

```
<Grid>
    <CustomWeekView:CustomWeekView x:Name="WeekView"></CustomWeekView:CustomWeekView>
</Grid>
```

All projects runs without any problem during debug. There is only one way to get rid of this error, but it is non permanent, which is by removing the CustomWeekView and re-add it. What I mean by non permanent is that the error re-appear if I close and re-open the Solution.

Anyone have an idea why this is happening? or how to investigate further?